# What type of camera is compatible with the Arduino Uno in which its pictures can be saved onto the SD card?

Tags: arduino, camera, sd

Researching interfacing a camera to the arduino, there is not a good amount of data out there.  Do any of you know the ways to do this and successfully be able to save the picture to the SD card for further use?  This is the best link I found so far: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=50578.0 and it suggested the use of a ttl camera (~$50).  Is there any alternative (namely cheaper camera?)  The camera doesn't have to be high quality.  Thanks for your inputs!!!

Comment: Cameras don't have to be designed for the Arduino Uno in order to work, you just need a camera that provides you with some sort of interface and then it is just a matter of programming for the camera.

Comment: Rolled back pointless and factually erroneous edit.  Do not hyperlink terms to wrong targets. TTL has nothing to do with lenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something with an asynchronous serial or spi or (maybe?) i2c type of interface is probably going to be best.  The Arduino's ATMEGA is a fairly limited chip, so something that requires a lot of work to talk to, either because it is very primitive, or because it uses a complicated protocol like USB, is probably not  good choice.

Needless to say, don't expect high frame rates.

Realistically, by the time you buy the camera, the Arduino, and shield with the SDCARD there are probably more capable platforms to be had for the money, but if you know Arduino you would not be the first to add this combination of things to it.